# Cannot forward X11 anymore from as ssh server

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, x11, osx

Since a few days ago I cannot forward X11 anymore on my machine from an ssh server and I can’t figure why.

I work on OSX 10.12 and ArchLinux as a guest virtual machine (VirtualBox hypervisor): when I try to log in the server with the `-X` flag I get

```
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
```

on OSX (same warning with `-Y` flag) and no warnings on Arch. Then whenever I try to execute GUI programs I get seg fault on both.

I tried to log in with another machine and everything worked fine, so I must assume there's something wrong with my machine, since I find the same problem with two different OS (can't figure how this is possible). Could be the new OSX 10.12, installed few days ago, the source of this trouble? Any other hint?

My `~/.ssh/config`:

```
    Host *
      ForwardAgent      yes
      ForwardX11        yes
      ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

I also regenerated the `~/.Xauthority` file, but nothing changed.

Comment: does `xauth list $DISPLAY` on your osx show an MIT magic cookie?

Comment: nope, it returns zero output...

Comment: I dont have a mac to help further. You might try this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39622173/5008284) on stackexchange which is similar, the [xquartz](https://www.xquartz.org/FAQs.html) faq, or posting on our sister site http://apple.stackexchange.com/